# limit of a floor function

Tags: real-analysis, limits, infinity, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I came across the following limit in a math book

$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{(x^x)}{E(x)^{E(x)}} $

where $E(x)$ represent the [floor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions) function, and the question was to prove that this limit doesn't exist, in order to do that the following indication was given 
 $ E(n+1/2)=n $
i am totally lost, and i don't have a clew how to proceed any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Write $f(x) = x^x/E(x)^{E(x)}$. Note that $E(x)$ is constant on intervals $[n,n+1)$ for integral $n$, and since $E(n) = n$ for integral $n$, we also have that $f(n)=1$. Thus $$f(1)=f(2)=f(3)=\cdots=f(n)=f(n+1)=\cdots$$ 
Now, can you show that $f(n +\frac12)$ is arbitarily large?

Comment: is there another "more" convincing way to prove that?

Comment: I have produced a sequence of points $x_n\to\infty$ with $f(x_n)\to 1$, so the limit must be $1$ if it exists, so $f(x)$ must be arbitrarily close to $1$ for all sufficiently large $x$. If you can demonstrate a sequence of points $y_n$ with $f(y_n)$ bounded away from $1$ ($f(y_n)\to\infty$ would certainly do that), then this contradicts the limit being $1$, so the limit wouldn't exist in that case. This would be a case of divergence by oscillation. Even finding $y_n\to\infty$ with $f(y_n)\geq 2$ would do it for the same reason. I think my suggested sequence does that.